# JQuery Animate setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout

As the subject, how can I set timeout for below jQuery?? Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateM();
});
function newPosition(){
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    return [nh,nw];
}
function animateM(){
    var newq =  newPosition();
    $('.animateM').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
        animateM();
    });
};
```

Comment: `setTimeout(animateM, 1000);`

Comment: if you just want to call the function `animateM()` with a delay just use `setTimeout(animateM, duration);`

Comment: `how can I set timeout for below jQuery?? `  what does that mean ? :) you want to setTimeout for calling the `animateM()` function ?

Comment: I want to run the animation move around the browser within a min, then the amination will disappear or still in the page

Answer (score 1):

In a basic scenario, the preferred, cross-browser way to pass parameters to a callback executed by `setTimeout` is by using an anonymous function as the first argument.:

```
function newPosition(){
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    return [nh,nw];
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var newq =  newPosition();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.animateM').animate({
            top: newq[0],
            left: newq[1],
        });
    , 2000 ); // 2000 is duration

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var newq =  newPosition();
$(".animateM").animate({left:newq[1]}, "2000")
           .animate({top:newq[0]}, "5000");
        
});
function newPosition(){
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    return [nh,nw];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div  class="animateM"  style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```